# Laravel ORM many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

Its Laravel 5.3

Stuck in objects relationships
I've some DB models like following

Here Customers can have multiple devices and devices can have multiple events

I want to get all events by customer, following code are my models having relationships defined..

When I try to get events like DeviceEvents::with(['customer'])->get(); it returns nothing but exception.. please help me to solve this ORM..

---

```
customer (Model: Customer)
========
id | name

function devices = $this->hasMany('App\Devices');
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
devices (Model: Devices)
========
id | customer_id | name

function customer = $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
function events = $this->hasMany('App\DeviceEvents');
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

event_logs (Model: DeviceEvents)
==========
id | device_id

function device = $this->belongsTo('App\Devices');
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I tried `Customer::with(['devices' => function($query) { 
$query->with('events');
}])->where('id', 'YOUR_CUSTOMER')->get();` but getting error 
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'device_events.customer_devices_id`

Comment: Can one device belong to multiple customers? Your database structure suggests it can

Comment: Nope, each device belongs to only one customer but customer can have multiple devices

Comment: What do you use the customer_devices table for? Won't customer_id in devices table be enough to link devices to customers?

Comment: Right.. so how about this

http://prntscr.com/e71b2r

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135401/discussion-between-muhammad-nawaz-memon-and-jedrzej-kurylo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent derives names of foreign key columns from relation names. You've named the relation **devices**, therefore Eloquent assumes that foreign key column is called **devices_id**. If you want to use different name, you need to specify that when creating the relation.

Replace

```
$this->belongsTo('App\Devices');
```

with

```
$this->belongsTo('App\Devices', 'device_id');
```

You should now be able to access customer's devices in **$customer->devices** and iterate through them to get list of events for each of them.

If you just want to get a list of events for all devices of given customer, you'll need to define a new has-many-through relation in **Customer** model:

```
public function events() {
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\DeviceEvents', 'App\Devices', 'customer_id', 'device_id', 'id');
}
```

Now, you can fetch customer and their events with:

```
$customer = Customer::with('events')->find('YOUR_CUSTOMER');
```

All events are available in **$customer->events** collection.

A few more tips:

You can eager-load nested relations in a much easier way:

```
//load customer with related devices and their events
Customer::with('devices.events')->find('YOUR_CUSTOMER');
```

I order to fetch a record by its primary key you could use **find()** method:

```
$customer = Customer::find('YOUR_CUSTOMER');
```